# Interdependent validation of form and formset

Tags: django, validation, django-forms

I have a view that allows the creation of an invoice by prompting for invoice header information through a normal Django form (`InvoiceForm`), and on the same page for line item information using a formset (`ItemForm`). This has worked fine for several years now.

I want to introduce a new validation criterion that references a value in the form (specifically, the invoice date) and a value in each formset entry (the tax rate). I can't see a way for the `InvoiceForm` validation function to reference the `ItemForm` values or vice-versa - will I just have to carry out the validation manually in the view and inject the errors into the otherwise valid forms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in the same page, and inside the same `<form>` tag, then you should be able to access each other in the validation Django POST back view (action of the form).

Your other method would be to use javascript/ajax calls to do validation between the two forms on the page.

Comment: OK, so basically as I suspected - I can't use the various `clean` functions, but will have to handle validation separately in the `if request.method == 'POST'` part of the view?

Comment: i belive so. you maybe able to create a combined custom form that inherits the two modelforms.